# Flask & Python, Simplifying missing parameter checks

Tags: python, flask

In Flask, when you request parameters from the frontend, you have something like the following:

```
    r = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)

    if not r:
        raise InvalidUsageError(
            message="Parameters must be included in the request body."
        )

    first_name = r.get("firstName", None)
    last_name = r.get("lastName", None)
    email = r.get("email", None)
    password = r.get("password", None)
    quiz_uuid = r.get("quizId", None)

    if not first_name:
        # Throw error
    if not last_name:
        # Throw error
    etc...
```

All of the if nots seem unnecessary, but if you still want granular error checks is there a simplified way of returning a string like

```
variable_name + " is missing from the request"
```

Or in general, is it not common to return these granular error checks?

Comment: Reads like you're after a data validation (aka marshaling/serialization) tool. Check out [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [Flask-Marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not to use individual names for the values.

```
    r = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)

    if not r:
        raise InvalidUsageError(
            message="Parameters must be included in the request body."
        )
    
    args = {}
    for name in ('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'quizId'):
        if name not in r:
            throw ValueError( f"{name} is missing from the request" }
        args[name] = r[name]
```

You just have to write `args['firstName']` instead of `first_name`.

Of course, that case, you could just write `r['firstName']` instead.